# 4 model B Ethernet not working

Tags: raspbian, ethernet

I connected an Ethernet cable to my raspberry pi 4B, and from what I hear, being normal, but it's not actually connecting to the internet. Green blinking, orange solid. Here's what happened: it was slowing down WiFi, and I use it via ssh, so I used `sudo rfkill block wifi`, and ssh went down. I was led to believe that it would only disable wireless connection to the internet, not Ethernet, though, then again, I'm not quite sure that it was connected via Ethernet in the first place.... Any advice? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I just turned on WiFi, but I'm not connected wirelessly, just through an ethernet cable, and it still seems to not be working. Any help?

Comment: I haven't the faintest idea what you are asking. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) If you have problems list some diagnostics and any files you modified.

Comment: I would start by finding out what IP address each port is using `ifconfig` and then use the Ethernet IP to connect to with `ssh pi@x.x.x.x` rather than by name. When you connected by Ethernet you can then sort out the WiFi.

Comment: Just to verify your network environment: flash an unmodified image [Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-os/) to your SD Card and use the wired connection. It must work out of the box. If not then the problem is not the Raspberry Pi. Does the wired connection worked then?

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask